# can not iterate through jasonArray properly and I get error

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json as follow:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "ff",
        "price": "ff",
        "unit": "Kg",
        "storeId": "2",
        "username": "fdf",
        "abb": "ff",
        "date": "02/11/2015"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "ff",
        "price": "ff",
        "unit": "Kg",
        "storeId": "2",
        "username": "yhyhyy",
        "abb": "ff",
        "date": "02/11/2015"
    }
]
```

Now I have this one as an string in a variable and I want to iterate through the json and get the name and price of each item in the array:
I found the following link and I followed that :
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963347/how-to-iterate-this-json-array-using-java-and-org-json-in-android)

and here is my code:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb);
JSONArray jsonPersonData = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonPersonData.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject item = jsonPersonData.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = item.getString("name");
    String surname = item.getString("price");
}
```

but unfortunately I get the following error:

> JSONArray[0] is not a JSONArray.

I do not know how I can do it?(I do not want to do it through string manipulation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this instead:

```
JSONArray jsonPersonData = new JSONArray(sb);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonPersonData.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject item = jsonPersonData.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = item.getString("name");
    String surname = item.getString("price");
}
```

You get the error because your JSON data is an array of JSON objects and  the link you referred to has JSON data that has more than one JSON array of JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

The json string is one array with two objects: `[ {...}, {...} ]`. Your code first reads the array through `new JSONArray(sb)` and then grabs the first item as another array: `jsonArray.getJSONArray(0)`. It should read the objects there already instead.